# How to get input value and set it in setText() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

im trying to get value from stringResource(R.string.Item_DetailHint)

And put it into mimeMessage.setText("here") so i can receive item details from user to email

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
   decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
     if (textState.text.isEmpty()) {
         body_grey50(
           stringResource(R.string.Item_DetailHint),
                   overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                 )
           }
    innerTextField()
  },
)
```

```
<string name="Item_DetailHint">Enter Item Details</string>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/itemDetailFragment"
    android:name="io.storedta.mystore.modules.managestore.itemdetail.Item_DetailFragment"/>
```

i tried

```
val x = stringResource(R.string.Item_DetailHint)

mimeMessage.setText(x)
```

but only received placeholder of input not value data

Any help will be great

Comment: What is `mimeMessage`? Are you using jetpack compose? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include all relevant tags.

Comment: @Ricky Mo i use androidx.compose i have updated my post please check

Comment: put your string tag into the strings.xml file